# compare data in 2 excel spreadsheets and then highlight common data in one excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007, conditional-formatting

I have a excel sheet with 2 tabs . In each tab there are some text written.

I need to compare values in column_1 in sheet 1 with values in column_2 of sheet2 and in case any similar values present I need to highlight the text in sheet1.

Also, suppose I copy some data from sheet1 to sheet2 (column_2) then shee1(column_1) need to be highlighted.

Note : 1. This should work only via conditional formatting or any other formulas.  I cannot use any macro

2. Don't mention that copy sheet1 and sheet2 in one sheet and apply formula. As I don't want to use that approach

Comment: You will need to create a range from each sheet for the areas you want to compare; then, loop through them and compare values; then, apply some formatting to the values you want to highlight.

Comment: If thr is any formula which will one let me know. This logic I know already.

Comment: Note : I need to use formula in conditional formatting only

Comment: I think what you really need to do is to google/bing these steps one at a time; I'm sure you'll find some examples, no doubt many of them from previous StackOverflow posts.

Comment: If in Visual Studio, you select Help > Samples and search for "Excel" you will find a project named "How to compare cells in Excel and highlight the cells that are different"

Answer (score 1):

Select column_1 in sheet 1 and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=COUNTIF(sheet2!$B:$B,A1)
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select colour Fill (highlight) of your choice, <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.

When copying from column_1 in sheet 1 to sheet2 the formatting may be transferred unless the choice is made not to.